# Android - search dialog with Custom Suggestions

Tags: android, search

I have a search dialog which needs to be suggestion enabled from the database as shown here http://developer.android.com/images/search/search-suggest-custom.png.

My search dialog will be shown at the top, when i click an action bar menu item. When the user starts typing in some text, it should search the db and display suggestions accordingly. As of now, i have a search dialog, but when the user types in some text, no suggestions are displayed.

my content provider:

```
public class MyCustomSuggestionProvider extends ContentProvider {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb;
    String sqlTables = "countries";

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {

        return false;
    }
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        MyDatabase myDB = new MyDatabase(getContext());
        db = myDB.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = null;

        if (selectionArgs != null && selectionArgs.length > 0
                && selectionArgs[0].length() > 0) {

            qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
            String[] sqlSelect = { "name" };
            qb.setTables(sqlTables)

                c = qb.query(db, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null,
                        null);
                c.moveToFirst();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        return c;
    }
    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

my manifest:

```
    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Visa" >
            <provider
                android:name="com.m7.visa.contentprovider.MyCustomSuggestionProvider"
                android:authorities="com.m7.visa.contentprovider.MyCustomSuggestionProvider" >
            </provider>

            <activity
                android:name="com.m7.visa.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.app.searchable"
                    android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
            </activity>
</application>
```

my searchable configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="hint..."
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.m7.visa.contentprovider.MyCustomSuggestionProvider"
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?" >

</searchable>
```

any idea where am i going wrong?

Comment: whats the error you are getting ?

Comment: @HarshaMV i am not getting any error, when i type in something in the search dialog, there is no sugesstion shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try remove space at line `android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?" >`

to `android:searchSuggestSelection="?" >`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the question mark `android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?" >`. When you typed 'something' in the search view, it would pass ' something', with the space on the left. So the solution is to remove the space, but '?' is a special character in Android XML files, that means you have to escape it.

So the final solution is `android:searchSuggestSelection="\?" >`